# terraform: how to upgrade Azure AKS default nodepool VM size without replacement of the cluster

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, azure-aks, azure-rm

I'm trying to upgrade the VM size of my AKS cluster using [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/resize-node-pool) approach with Terraform. Basically I create a new nodepool with the required amount of nodes, then I cordon the old node to disallow scheduling of new pods. Next, I drain the old node to reschedule all the pods in the newly created node. Then, I proceed to upgrade the VM size.

The problem I am facing is that `azurerm_kubernetes_cluster` resource allow for the creation of the `default_node_pool` and another resource, `azurerm_kuberentes_cluster_node_pool` allows me to create new nodepools with extra nodes.

Everything works until I create the new nodepool, cordon and drain the old one. However when I change the `default_nod_pool.vm_size` and run `terraform apply`, it tells me that the whole resource has to be recreated, including the new nodepool I just created, because it's linked to the cluster id, which will be replaced.

How should I manage this upgrade from the documentation with Terraform if upgrading the default node pool always forces replacement even if a new nodepool is in place?

```sh
terraform version

terraform v1.1.7
on linux_amd64
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm v2.82.0
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/local v2.2.2
```

Comment: From the code [here](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/blob/main/internal/services/containers/kubernetes_nodepool.go#L50-L55), I see `ForceNew:     true,` set. I'm not sure if it's hard requirement of the API. Have you tried using API, if it works with API, the `ForceNew:     true,` needs to be removed.

Comment: I did some more research and, apparently, there's no way to do it because of how Terraform creates the cluster and requires a default node pool to exist at all time. This blog post gives a nice detailed explanation on how to workaround it: https://pumpingco.de/blog/modify-aks-default-node-pool-in-terraform-without-redeploying-the-cluster/.